# How can I use python variables in a class?

Tags: python, class, syntax-error, class-variables

When I define the class C as follows:

```
class C:
  a = [0,1,2]
  m = dict([(i, a[i]) for i in a])
```

it generates the following error:

> NameError: name 'a' is not defined

I tried to replace **a** with **C.a** but it says:

> NameError: name 'C' is not defined

Any idea is appreciated

Comment: try class C(object): ...

Comment: @ManuelHess Sublclassing `object` was the way in Python 2 to get 'new style' classes, which are the only existing ones in Python 3, and is just ignored now. See the duplicate for a very thorough explanation of what is going on and how to circumvent it.

Comment: create variables in `__init__`.